# iOS Push Notification Failed to connect: 111 Connection refused

Tags: php, ios, codeigniter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am getting following error on my live server but same code work perfect in my Local PC.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection refused)

Filename: controllers/Appcar.php

Line Number: 657

Backtrace:

File: /home/aistech/public_html/mywhipp/application/controllers/Appcar.php
Line: 657
Function: stream_socket_client

File: /home/aistech/public_html/mywhipp/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

I dont know what actually issue here. I tried everything but not getting success.

Answer (score 0):

For sending push notifications to iOS device from php , we need to hit the APN urls.
The APN urls are different for different environments

```
ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 - development
ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 - production.
```

As you sed it was working in local not in production,in error message it was displaying sandbox URL,for production you need to change the URL.

```
if ($production) {
    $gateway = 'gateway.push.apple.com:2195';
} else { 
    $gateway = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195';
}
```

Comment: I used your code but getting this error: `Message: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection refused)`

Comment: Check with certificates. For development and production different certificates. i.e ck.pem file.